# How to prevent LXDE from popping up a textbox when I press Super+<AlphaNumeric Key>?

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04, lxde

When I press Super and an Alphanumeric character I get a textbox whose use I was unable to figure out. The only problem with this textbox is that it prevents me from using HotKeys such as Super+W because they invoke that textbox instead of the command I assigned to them.

I am using Lubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

The action of pressing a alphanumeric key *while the desktop* is in focus, moves the focus to an application or to a file or to a folder present on your desktop *whose name starts with that alphanumeric character*. If there's more than one match, you'd need to type in additional characters until the item you wish to select (or find) is highlighted. It's a sort of visual "find" possibly useful on a busy desktop with several icons of files or applications. Pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> isn't necessary.

For example, if I have shortcut links to Firefox or LXTerminal, and the desktop is in focus, pressing <kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd> will highlight Firefox or LXTerminal, respectively.

This also works for files on your desktop.

- Run `touch a.txt ab.txt abc.txt` from a terminal while in your Desktop sub-directory
- Make sure that no application window has focus and that you can see the three files you created
- Press <kbd>a</kbd>: the text box appears and file `a.txt` is highlighted
- While still in the text box, press <kbd>b</kbd> so that the contents of the box are now `ab`. See that the focus changes to file `ab.txt`. The same thing happens if you type `c`. The focus will move to `abc.txt`
- In other words, while the desktop is active, this feature to search the desktop is available.

Now, to address the issue of the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and that you can't access hot keys you set.

First, while there maybe a graphical interface to set hot keys, I directly edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` using a plain text editor (after ensuring that the original `lubuntu-rc.xml` is safely backed up). Edits done this way take effect in the same session only after you run `openbox --reconfigure`. Or you can log out and log back in. Running this command also performs a very useful parsing check on your `xml` file.

Second, if you have a valid hotkey shortcut assigned and functional, pressing say <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> whether the desktop is in focus or not will open the application you specify with `W-L` as the "keybind" where "W" is used to refer to the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

You can test this by having the LXTerminal shortcut icon on your desktop and defining the `W-L` keybind to open `Leafpad`. Pressing just <kbd>l</kbd> when the desktop is in focus will highlight the LXTerminal icon whereas pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> will open Leafpad whether or not the desktop or any other application has focus.